# Resteasy exports dates in textual format on wildfly 14 (Java 11) as opposed to numeric format in wildfly 9 (Java 8)

Tags: java, datetime, jackson, wildfly, resteasy

I have a project that works fine on Java 8 running on Wildfly 9.

I use some REST endpoints to serialize some Java objects to JSON. This is configured with Resteasy and `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.

I'm now trying to convert the project to work on wildfly 14 and Java 11.

For some reason in the previous version, `Date`objects were exported as a numeric value. In the new environment, dates are exported in a textual format (e.g. `2018-12-03T10:05:33.39Z[UTC]`).

The strange thing is that some data properties of some objects are still exported in the numeric format and others are exported in the textual format.

I've tried enabling the `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` feature but this doesn't change the result.

```
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonConfig  implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    public JacksonConfig()
    {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> objectType)
    {
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not answering your question, I’d prefer the textual format. I suppose the numeric format goes like `1543833647428`, quite unreadable for humans.

Comment: @OleV.V., I'm actually wondering if this format is even a valid textual format. I do agree that it would be better to use a textual format but it would also require me to make changes in the front-end of the application.

Comment: `2018-12-03T10:05:33.39Z[UTC]` is *almost* [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), the international standard. Only `[UTC]` is a Java specific addition. If you can persuade Jackson to omit that, it shouldn’t be too hard to adapt your frontend to the rest (or it could ignore any part in square brackets at the end and be happy about what comes before it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to the switch from jackson to jsonb.

It is further explained in this [thread](https://developer.jboss.org/message/986761).